# Keeping a long-running task running on exactly one machine of a cluster with failover?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, failover, jgroups

I have a low-CPU queue processing task that I need to keep running for a potentially long period of time. In case the task fails, I'd like to have the task running in a high-availability clustered environment, and the task should "switch" to another machine if the first machine fails. What is the best way to make sure that I have the task running on exactly one machine in the cluster at a time, with seamless failover on machine failure?

Right now, I'm planning to use [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org) to implement this feature. I'll keep one channel for each task, and only the channel leader will execute the task while the other members "follow along." Then, if the channel leader ever changes, the new channel leader picks up where the last one left off.

Has anyone used JGroups to solve this problem? What was your experience?

Comment: I cant comment on experience with JGroup, but certainly it is capable of doing it. For our (at my work) requirement we wrote simple UDP based cluster framework. Framework host election and choose leader, if leader dies then one of the member  start election.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That's great information.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some inspiration and direction from the JBoss 4.2.3+ [Clustered Singleton](https://community.jboss.org/message/210139). The define a service that runs on one, and only one node in a cluster of nodes. If that node fails, or is ejected from the cluster, a new node is assigned the singleton. The underlying implementation [of JBoss Clustering] is JGroups.

Comment: This looks excellent. I'll have a look and will accept this answer if it works out.